# how to remove the value counts in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a dataframe with unique numbers and their value counts in a dataframe. I would like to remove the value counts to get the mean of the numbers.

I have tried to convert it to a string and then slice it. `randompicks2 = randompicks.to_string()` then `randompicks2 = randompicks2[0:38]` which gives me the 6 digit random number without the value counts, but I can't convert the string to a number, or do any math's on them. Below is the data set. The random numbers are from 1-69 and if the values change to much it will add or subtract an element in the string, so the strings can and will change every time.

So in the program I needed the value counts. And now I need to do some functions on the random numbers without the value counts messing up the data, for example doing mean, finding the sum, and so on. I have also tried to convert the string to a numpy array, and just straight slicing from the dataframe.  `randompicks2 = randompicks2[0:15]`
all I get back with that is the same dataframe below.

I just need the very top row of numbers,ie the 11,16,18,50,69,3

I added the dots to make the spacing correct.

> ...  11    ...  16   ...   28  ...    50 ...     69  ......    3
>
> 0  61.0   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
>
> 1   NaN  43.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
>
> 2   NaN   NaN  35.0   NaN   NaN   NaN
>
> 3   NaN   NaN   NaN  35.0   NaN   NaN
>
> 4   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  42.0   NaN
>
> 5   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  51.0

some more sample data:using `print(df).to_dict` and `print(df.columns)`

{2: {0: 101.0, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan}, 16: {0: nan, 1: 43.0, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan}, 39: {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: 39.0, 3: nan, 4: nan}, 47: {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: 41.0, 4: nan}, 53: {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: 51.0}, 10: {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan}}
Int64Index([2, 16, 39, 47, 53, 10], dtype='int64')

And some of the first few of the df that I draw the random numbers from.

0     1    2   3   4     5

2  101.0   6.0  NaN NaN NaN  43.0

3   97.0  11.0  NaN NaN NaN  51.0

4   89.0  19.0  2.0 NaN NaN  56.0

1   88.0   NaN  NaN NaN NaN  57.0

6   68.0  26.0  1.0 NaN NaN  56.0

Comment: Will you please provide a sample of your dataframe with `print(df.head(5).to_dict())`? And also `print(df.columns)`

Comment: {2: {0: 101.0, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan}, 16: {0: nan, 1: 43.0, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan}, 39: {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: 39.0, 3: nan, 4: nan}, 47: {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: 41.0, 4: nan}, 53: {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: 51.0}, 10: {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan}} Int64Index([2, 16, 39, 47, 53, 10], dtype='int64')

python
pandas
dataframe

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
l = df.columns.tolist()
print(l)
```

Output:

```
[2, 16, 39, 47, 53, 10]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just do `list` call

```
l = list(df)
```